# What is meant by usual topology in this content

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I am currently doing a problem sheet in topology.

"We equip $[0, 1)$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ and $S^1$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{C}$ with their usual subspace topologies. Consider the map $p:[0,1)\rightarrow{S^1}$ given by $p(t)=\exp(2\pi{}it)$.

Show that $p$ is a continuous bijection. Show that $p$ is not a homeomorphism."

What is meant by 'their usual topologies' for the spaces. And furthermore, to go ahead with the problem, do I simply take an arbritary open set in image and show that its pre-image is open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is meant by 'their usual topologies' for the spaces

In the task it is mentioned that the sets are equiped with their usual subspace topologies.
The subspace topology of a subset $A$ of some topological space $X$ is defined by:

$\tau_A=\{V\subseteq A| V=U\cap A~\text{where $U\subseteq X$ is open}\}$.

So for example the set $[0,\frac12)$ is open in $[0,1)$ (with regards to the usual subspace topology on $[0,1)$), because $(-1,\frac12)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ (with regards to the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, which is induced by the absolute value $|\cdot|$)

Since $[0,\frac12)=[0,1)\cap (-1,\frac12)$.

Keep in mind that $[0,\frac12)$ is not(!) open in $\mathbb{R}$ (with the usual topology).

> And furthermore, to go ahead with the problem, do I simply take an arbritary open set in image and show that its pre-image is open?

You have to show that $p$ is not a homeomorphism.

$p: [0,1)\to S^1, p(t)=\operatorname{exp}(2\pi it)$, is a homeomorphism if $p$ is continuous, bijective and its inverse $p^{-1}$ is also continuous.

If you show that the preimage of an open set in $S^1$ is open, you showed that $p$ is continuous. (That is indeed true)
But you want to show that this $p$ is not a homeomorphism.

So you have to either show that $p$ is not bijective, or $p^{-1}$ is not continuous. Some of these properties have to fail.

Comment: I am now trying to prove p is continuous (out of curiosity), how would you choose an arbritary open set in the image $S^1$? I tried to take two points in $S^1$ and consider the open ball with a centre at the midpoint and radius equal to the distance from the midpoint to one of the two points. This seems wrong, is this correct, if not how would you choose an appropriate arbitrary open set.

Comment: @Sam. S The thing is that you do not have to show it (preimage of an open set is open) for one arbitrary open set, but for all open sets. That is at least one method. I do not think it is the easiest here. But you had to begin like this: Let $U\subseteq S^1$ be open. We need to show that $p^{-1}(U)$ is open. That $p$ is continuous is 'clear' because $\operatorname{exp}$ is a continuous function. I understand if that is not satisfying for you. Also there are other methods to proof that a function is continuous, which might be more suitable.